# Diagonalizable operator with single spectrum and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f:V \to V$ a linear diagonalizable operator with single spectrum (i.e., all distinct eigenvalues). Prove that the vector space dimension of the operators that commute with $f$ is equal to $\dim V$ in this case.

Comment: Use that diagonalizable linear operators are simultaneously diagonalizable iff they commute.